# Giving a SQL query a title in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm building a console application to push out several different reports via email and including the report attached in a .CSV file.

The reports are coming from SQL Server, some are Stored Proc's, others are (lazily) statically typed for now.

However I was wondering if there was a way to give a name / title dynamically to a query table based on what was being returned? Reason being is that the Report Email subject and attachment will be based off of that query and I would like it to dynamically reflect the query the was being run.

I'm aware I could within the Proc's/Query add a column with blank data, name the column the title of the report and then remove the column from the results presented, but this seems a bit hacked together and I wondered if there was a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you querying the database? ADO.NET?

Comment: how about creating `Views` and giving them descriptive names such as `Last_Order_By_All_Customers` and then you can simply do a `SELECT * FROM Last_Order_By_All_Customers`

Comment: Hmm Views seems good, has some security benefits too...!

I'll let you know if that is my solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the easiest and quickest answer was just to create a temporary column in the Stored Proc and then use that when labelling the excel tab.

Views probably could have done the job, but required more effort for reasonably little benefit.

Thanks!